# Determine if multiple timelines are overlapping in R

Tags: r

I wonder what could be the best way to determine overlapping time-lines in a large dataset? For example, in the following dataframe, all time ranges are overlapping except German E and French J. Ideally I want to add a Yes/No column to the dataframe to determine overlaps.

Here is the reproducible example:

```
library(plyr);library(dplyr)
library(googleVis)

df <- data.frame(Language = structure(c(rep("English",7), rep("German",5), rep("French", 10)), class = "character"),
                 Students = c(LETTERS[1:7], LETTERS[1:5], LETTERS[1:10]), 
                 Start = structure(c(16713,16713,16713,16744,16713,16714,16754,16729,16729,16729,16750,16769,
                                     16724,16724,16745,16724,16759,16766,16723,16722,16736,16796), class = "Date"), 
                 End = structure(c(16762,16720,16762,16755,16720,16764,16762,16765,16765,16749,16761,16770,16758,
                                   16744,16758,16764,16765,16766,16726,16723,16758,16806), class = "Date"))

ddply(df, .(Language), summarise,
      FirstDay = min(Start),
      LastDay = max(End), 
      Duration = LastDay - FirstDay)

plot(gvisTimeline(data=df, rowlabel = "Class", start = "Start", end = "End", options=list(width=600, height=1000) ))
```

[image]

Comment: F is not overlapping with others, right?

Comment: If your data contains "Date" class, you could try with "IRanges" package: `lapply(split(IRanges(as.vector(df$Start), as.vector(df$End), names = df$Students), df$Language), overlapsAny, ignoreSelf = TRUE)`

Comment: `df$overlap <- sapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) any((df$Start[i] <= df$End[-i]) & (df$End[i] >= df$Start[-i])))`

Comment: Yes JasonWang, E, F and J are not overlapping.